# Alternating Column Colors SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am making a chart in SSRS.  I have two sets of columns - one stacked on top of the other.  I would like the columns on top to be one color and the columns on bottom to be another.  How can I do this?

Comment: You need to use stacked bar chart.

Comment: Alright, I've done that.  However, whenever I want to select the lower bars, I cannot do it.  It selects all of the columns - both top and bottom.  How can I change this?

Comment: Why do you want to select 1 column?